# Match zero-width wildcard in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

tl;dr: I want to build `base.ext` and `base_variant.ext` from the same rule.

I regularly have a Makefile that can build a bunch of variants of some target, with the default version begin something like `base.ext` and variants for example `base_variant.ext`. Those are built from the same (set of) sources with just some small differences. Those rules can be pretty complicated and I'd really like not repeating them.

I've come to be gradually more annoyed as years go by that I can't just use something like the Makefile below:

```
options = ...
%_variant.ext: options += ....

base%.ext: sources
    command $^ $(options) > $@
```

This is a pattern that really comes back a lot, for different uses of Makefiles. It can be for building executables, this could be something like:

```
SRC=$(wildcard *.c)
%_instr.o:%.c
     $(CC) -some-instrumentation-flags $^ -o $@

# Ideally I would like this rule to build foo from implicit-rules binaries,
# and foo_instr from the objects generated by the rule above
foo%:$(SRC:.c=%.o)
     $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

In the effort of providing an MCVE, here's an example with beamer presentations, where `beamer.pdf` is the baseline version, `beamer_notes.pdf` has "notes on second screen" enabled, and `beamer_handout.pdf` is a denser version with less pages:

```tex
% beamer.tex
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,pdfusetitle,17pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\mode<handout:0>{\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}}
\mode<handout:1>{\setbeameroption{hide notes}}
\title{some talk} \author{some author}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Hello world}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

```
# Makefile
SRC=beamer.tex

options:=
default:$(SRC:.tex=.pdf)

handout:$(SRC:.tex=_handout.pdf)
handout:options:=handout

notes:$(SRC:.tex=_notes.pdf)
notes:options:=notes

$(SRC:.tex=%.pdf):$(SRC)
    pdflatex -jobname="$(@:.pdf=)" '\PassOptionsToClass{$(options)}{beamer}\input{$<}'
    # here a bunch more rules potentially to deal with bibliographies etc

.PHONY:default handout notes
```

Now this Makefile doesn't work as I would like:

```
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target 'beamer.pdf', needed by 'default'.  Stop.
```

However `make handout` and `make notes` work as expected. Is there *any way* to make this work?

---

So far I've found 3 imperfect ways:

- changing the final rule to `%: $(SRC)`, however this becomes a mess as soon as you have more than one rule in a Makefile
- have the default target building `beamer_.pdf` (and generally start living in a world where all default targets have a stupid `base_.ext` name with a trailing underscore)
- add a rule that builds `beamer_.pdf` and moves it to `beamer.pdf`:
  `beamer_.pdf: beamer.pdf
      mv $< $@`
  However now this rule is never satisfied and `beamer_.pdf` is always rebuilt, even when `beamer.pdf` is newer than its sources. I've experimented with making `beamer_.pdf` PHONY but to no avail.

Did anyone else encounter this problem and find a satisfying solution?

Comment: One obvious problem (I think) -- you have a `%` in `$(SRC:.tex=%.pdf):$(SRC)` but only on one side of the substitution.  Try `$(SRC:.tex=.pdf):$(SRC)` or $(SRC:%.tex=%.pdf):$(SRC).

Comment: How about a `beamer%pdf` rule (with no dot)? Or a [canned recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes)?

Comment: @G.M. No that's fine, I want to create the rule `base%.pdf: base.tex` and that line does just that

Comment: @Beta yes matching the `.` works where there is an extension, you're right. It's probably canned recipes I was looking for, feel free to write that as an answer.

Comment: The reason is that pattern rules don't match empty pattern strings: _"The target is a pattern for matching file names; the ‘%’ matches any nonempty substring"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With versions of `make` prior to 3.82, there was a rather simple solution:

```
# Makefile
SRC=beamer.tex

default: $(SRC:.tex=.pdf)
handout: $(SRC:.tex=_handout.pdf)
notes: $(SRC:.tex=_notes.pdf)

$(SRC:.tex=.pdf) $(SRC:.tex=_%.pdf) : $(SRC)
    pdflatex -jobname="$(@:.pdf=)" '\PassOptionsToClass{$*}{beamer}\input{$<}

.PHONY:default handout notes
```

That is, you could use the same sources and rules for two target specifications, a nonpattern one (explicit rule) and a patterned one (implicit rule). It used to work. Unfortunately, this syntax was deprecated in version 3.82.

However, in version 4.1 it was accepted again, albeit with a warning.
From the file `NEWS` in the sources:

> - Change the fatal error for mixed explicit and implicit rules, that was
>     introduced in GNU make 3.82, to a non-fatal error.  However, this syntax
>     is still deprecated and may return to being illegal in a future version of 
>     GNU make. Makefiles that rely on this syntax should be fixed.

In fact, many makefiles in the linux kernel sources were still using it, and probably are. (Read *Relaxed constraints for mixing explicit and implicit rules* [here](https://blog.melski.net/2015/01/12/whats-new-in-gnu-make-4-1/) for more information.)

As of the current version, 4.2, it still works, with a warning. However, it is not a permanent solution because it might go away again.

Canned recipes, already mentioned in comments, are the way to go. Note that `$*` is treated differently: when used in recipes for implicit rules, it expands to the value of the stem (the string that matched `%`), while in recipes for explicit rules it is either empty or, if the target ends in a “known” suffix, it expands to the target without the suffix.

```
# Makefile
SRC=beamer.tex

define my_rules
pdflatex -jobname="$(@:.pdf=)" '\PassOptionsToClass{$*}{beamer}\input{$<}
# Other complicated rules...
endef

default: $(SRC:.tex=.pdf)
handout: $(SRC:.tex=_handout.pdf)
notes: $(SRC:.tex=_notes.pdf)

$(SRC:.tex=.pdf) : $(SRC)
    $(my_rules) 

$(SRC:.tex=_%.pdf) : $(SRC)
    $(my_rules)

.PHONY:default handout notes
```